# warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)

Tags: c, gcc, dll, shared-libraries

I'm creating a shared (.DLL) library and I keep getting this message from the compiler (gcc):

```
json.c:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
```

What does it mean that all code is position independent?

How a position dependent code looks like?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_independent_code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does it mean that all code is position independent?

It means that on your platform, *all* code is compiled *as if* `-fPIC` is on command line, whether you specify it or not (and the flag is therefore redundant).

You can safely ignore that warning.